# Android Volley - Bypass the certificate validation dynamically

Tags: android, android-volley

In my Android application, I am using Volley network library. I have to give an option to the user in app so that if it is enabled, I need to bypass the certificate validation while making the network connection. If its not enabled, I have disable the bypass validation coding part so that the connection will establish if the server is having valid certificate.

Can someone suggest me how can I switch between these two dynamically?

I have used the following code to bypass the validation.

```
/**
* By passing SSL
*/
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem as mentioned below.

Define the final objects for default ssl socket factory and default hostname verifier as

```
// define the default variables for proper certificate validation
private static final SSLSocketFactory defaultSSLSocketFactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
private static final HostnameVerifier defaultSSLHostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
```

I have defined the below 3 methods.

```
private void setDefaultSettingsForHttpsConnection(){
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(defaultSSLSocketFactory);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(defaultSSLHostnameVerifier);
}

/**
 * By passing SSL
 */
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
private void bypassSSLValidation() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkAndHandleSSLHandshake(Activity activity){
    if(SPUtils.getBoolean(activity, SPUtils.KEY_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED_PREF)){
        bypassSSLValidation();
    }else{
        setDefaultSettingsForHttpsConnection();
    }
}
```

Before adding the network request to queue, I am calling checkAndHandleSSLHandshake(context) so that it will change the settings dynamically for every request.